# GrayLog, can not see any logs

Tags: graylog

I install it as:

```
$ docker run --name mongo -d mongo:3
$ docker run --name elasticsearch -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 \
    -e ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms2g -Xmx4g" \
    -e "discovery.type=single-node" -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" \
    -e "bootstrap.memory_lock=true" --ulimit memlock=-1:-1 \
    -d docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.11
$ docker run --name graylog --link mongo --link elasticsearch \
    -p 9000:9000 -p 12201:12201 -p 514:514 -p 5555:5555 \
    -e GRAYLOG_WEB_ENDPOINT_URI="http://127.0.0.1:9000/api" \
    -d graylog/graylog:3.0.0
```

Then created a tcp input for 127.0.0.1 with port 5555 on graylog ui. Started it.

Then send a msg from the console:

```
echo "Test message" | nc 127.0.0.1 5555
```

But can not find this (or any other msg) anywhere in the graylog.

Did I miss something?.

Created HTTP GELF input, on test

```
curl -XPOST http://127.0.0.1:5555/gelf -p0 -d '{"short_message":"Hello there", "host":"example.org", "facility":"test", "_foo":"bar"}'
```

got:

```
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 2):

you should re-read on Graylog 3.0 - what have [changed](http://docs.graylog.org/en/3.0/pages/upgrade/graylog-3.0.html). The Docker information include all necessary information ( http://docs.graylog.org/en/3.0/pages/installation/docker.html ).

TLDR;

```
GRAYLOG_WEB_ENDPOINT_URI
```

Is no longer a valid Graylog configuration parameter. The new parameter to us is:

- http_bind_address
- http_publish_uri

Read the docs for what is what: http://docs.graylog.org/en/3.0/pages/configuration/server.conf.html#web-rest-api

**EDIT: Added complete commands**
Just to post the complete needed commands:

```
   $ docker run --name mongo -d mongo:3
   $ docker run --name elasticsearch \
      -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" \
      -e "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m" \
      -d docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-oss:6.6.1
   $ docker run --name graylog --link mongo --link elasticsearch \
      -p 9000:9000 -p 12201:12201 -p 514:514 \
      -e GRAYLOG_HTTP_EXTERNAL_URI="http://127.0.0.1:9000/" \
      -d graylog:latest
```

Comment: I tired those 3 commands. With that configuration I got: graylog/graylog:3.0 : "Up 6 seconds (health: starting)" and I can not reach localhost:9000 at all.